# Chamar valor de input dentro de span

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, input

Tenho essa linha de código:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usado" placeholder="Quantidade" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" onclick="usaEstoque(usado,<?php echo $arrDados['produto']; ?>)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span></span>
```

Estou tentando pegar o valor do input e o valor do id do produto (este funcionando em outros botões), afim de retirar a quantidade colocada no input do estoque. Em linhas gerais, estou tentando atualizar o estoque na própria página.

Criei a função em javascript pra testar:

```
function usaEstoque(usado,id){

  var qtdUsado = usado;
  var idProduto = id;
  alert(qtdUsado, idProduto)
};
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer especificamente com 'atualizar o estoque na própria página'? Você faz acesso a banco para dar `UPDATE` ou essa atualização é só em memória com Javascript?

Comment: Acesso ao banco. Eu já tenho uma procedure pronta pra isso, só estou travando na hora de conseguir os dados para passar pra função JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usado" placeholder="Quantidade" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" onclick="usaEstoque(<?php echo $arrDados['produto']; ?>)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span></span>
```

E na sua função:

```
function usaEstoque(id){
    var qtdUsado = document.getElementById("usado").value;
    var idProduto = id;
    alert(qtdUsado + " - " + idProduto);
};
```

Na chamada do clique você não precisa passar a referência ou o id do input em questão, caso ele não mude. Se sempre for o mesmo, pode pegar ele dentro da função com o [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: Eu achava que deveria ter algum tipo de submit pra conseguir o valor do input, por isso tentava chamar na função. Obrigado.